# OrientDB can't get graph instance using remote from java

Tags: java, orientdb

I created a database named "testing" and started the server, but when I try to get a graph instance from it using 'remote' ...

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("REMOTE:localhost:2424/testing", "admin", "admin");
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();  <--- THIS LINE
```

... it gives this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Cannot check the existance of a database in a remote server. Please
>   use the console or the OServerAdmin class.    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.exists(OStorageRemote.java:282)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.exists(OStorageRemoteThread.java:170)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.exists(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1160)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.openOrCreate(OrientBaseGraph.java:1902)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.(OrientBaseGraph.java:181)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:102)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:98)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.(OrientGraph.java:77)
>     at testing.testing.main(testing.java:202)

The OServerAdmin class doesn't provide any utility to get a graph instance as well.

Tested on OrientDB v2.1.9

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to open a DB in remote mode you have to use OServerAdmin class and then you can use OrientGraphFactory.
I attached you an example.

[image]